# OpenCV giving the following error as output

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, face-detection

```py
import cv2 #For Image processing 
import numpy as np #For converting Images to Numerical array 
import os #To handle directories 
from PIL import Image #Pillow lib for handling images 

labels = ["Harmeet", "Niti"] 

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'/home/niti/Downloads/facerasp/facerecog/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read(r"/home/niti/Downloads/facerasp/facerecog/face-trainner.yml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Get vidoe feed from the Camera

while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read() # Break video into frames 
    gray  = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert Video frame to Greyscale
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5) #Recog. faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] #Convert Face to greyscale 

    id_, conf = recognizer.predict(roi_gray) #recognize the Face

    if conf>=80:
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #Font style for the name 
        name = labels[id_] #Get the name from the List using ID number 
        cv2.putText(img, name, (x,y), font, 1, (0,0,255), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('Preview',img) #Display the Video
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems to give the following error.

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        10 face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'/home/niti/Downloads/facerasp/facerecog/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
>        11 recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
>   ---> 12 recognizer.read(r"/home/niti/Downloads/facerasp/facerecog/face-trainner.yml")
>        13 
>        14 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Get vidoe feed from the Camera
>
> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:2068: error: (-215:Assertion failed) isMap() in function 'operator[]'

Comment: You need to provide more information, like what you are trying to achieve, what the expected output is etc.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14908

Comment: this is the face detection code...I want am currently working on a face recognition project...On looking for the solution of the error on github..i found it can be removed on generating a new xml file after retraining...how am I supposed to do that.